# Unknown Java Result Message

Tags: java

I was running a code to retrieve XML documents from the web and simultaneously parsing them to extract some information. I was doing it for about 5000 documents. After a certain point the code hung up. The process had not completed. So I stop it and got the following message.

```
`Java Result: 2147483647`
```

What does it mean? Thanks

Comment: It's mean that you reach the end of Universe

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170762/what-does-java-result-means

Comment: as to why it hung up, most likely memory was growing tight and you were thrashing wildly creating free memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the exit code from the (JVM) process. Specifically, it's the one you'll get when you kill it.