# Java Result: 143

Tags: netbeans, ant, compiler-errors, java

What does this output mean?

```
init:
Deleting: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
run:
Java Result: 143
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 minutes 7 seconds)
```

I can't find much on what "Java Result" means.  In this case, the program hangs and then I kill Java, and then after restarting Netbeans I saw this output.

Related question: [what-does-java-result-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170762/what-does-java-result-means)

Is this from Ant?  Netbeans?  the JVM?  Presumably it's a code which you can look up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

143 is the exit code for the SIGTERM OS signal received by the process kicked off in the run task of your ant script (another JVM or native process perhaps). In this case, it was triggered as a result of calling kill.